# Find minimum volume bounded by three planes and another plane tangent to an ellipsoid.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am having trouble with a problem that I found in a multivariate calculus book. The problem is :

> Let $a$, $b$, and $c$ be nonzero real numbers. Find the minimum volume bounded by the planes given by $x=0$, $y=0$, $z=0$, and a plane that is tangent to the ellipsoid given
> by $\frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}} + \frac{y^{2}}{b^{2}} + \frac{z^{2}}{c^{2}} = 1$.

I suspect that solving this problem would involve the use of the Lagrange multiplier method.

In my solution so far I start with defining a function :
\begin{equation}
h(x,y,z) = \frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}} + \frac{y^{2}}{b^{2}} + \frac{z^{2}}{c^{2}} - 1
\end{equation}
So that the ellipse (call it $E$) is given by :
\begin{equation}
E = \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^{3} \; : \; h(x,y,z) = 0 \}
\end{equation}
We have the partial derivatives of $h$ as :
\begin{align}
h_{x}(x,y,z) & = \frac{2x}{a^{2}}\\
h_{y}(x,y,z) & = \frac{2y}{b^{2}}\\
h_{z}(x,y,z) & = \frac{2z}{c^{2}}
\end{align}
Now let $(x_{0},y_{0},z_{0}) \in E$. The tangent plane to E at $(x_{0},y_{0},z_{0})$ can be defined implicitly using a function $T$ :
\begin{align}
T_{x_{0},y_{0},z_{0}}(x,y,z) & = h_{x}(x_{0},y_{0},z_{0})(x-x_{0}) + h_{y}(x_{0},y_{0},z_{0})(y-y_{0}) + h_{z}(x_{0},y_{0},z_{0})(z-z_{0}) \\
  & = \frac{2x_{0}(x-x_{0})}{a^{2}} + \frac{2y_{0}(y-y_{0})}{b^{2}} + \frac{2z_{0}(z-z_{0})}{c^{2}}\\
\end{align}
Where the tangent plane (say $Q(x_{0},y_{0},z_{0})$) is :
\begin{equation}
Q(x_{0},y_{0},z_{0}) = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^{3} \; : \; T_{x_{0},y_{0},z_{0}}(x,y,z) =0 \}
\end{equation}
So I suspect the point of the problem is to find the $(x_{0},y_{0},z_{0}) \in E$ so that
the volume bounded by the planes defined by $Q(x_{0},y_{0},z_{0})$ , $x = 0$, $y=0$, and $z = 0$ is minimized. The problem that I have at this point is how to get an expression for this volume.

Can anyone help with this ?

Comment: You are complicating it. The equation of the plane is $\frac{x x_0}{a^2}+ \frac{y y_0}{b^2} + \frac{z z_0}{c^2} = 1$. WLOG take first quadrant. So the volume of the region is $\frac{a^2b^2c^2}{6 x_0 y_0 z_0}$. That means you need to maximize $x_0 y_0 z_0$ given the constraint $x_0^2 / a^2 + y_0^2 / b^2 + z_0^2 / c^2 = 1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is much, much easier to perform a coordinate transformation that takes the ellipse to the sphere:  $$(u, v, w) = (x/a, y/b, z/c)$$ and then observe that this transformation preserves tangency and scales volume proportionally by a factor of $1/(abc)$.

Then, since the sphere is symmetric, the minimum volume in the $(u,v,w)$ coordinate space is attained when the point of tangency is $u = v = w = 1/\sqrt{3}$ (why?).  Solve for the points where this plane intersects the $u$-, $v$-, and $w$-axes, compute the volume of the tetrahedron, and reverse the scaling transformation by multiplying by $abc$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

With the help of Lagrange multipliers

Calling $\Pi\to n_1 x+n_1 y+n_3 z = 1$ we have the lagrangian

$$
L=\frac 16 \frac{1}{n_1n_2n_3} + \lambda(n_1 x+n_1 y+n_3 z - 1)+\mu\left(\frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}} + \frac{y^{2}}{b^{2}} + \frac{z^{2}}{c^{2}} - 1\right)
$$

and the stationary points are the solutions for

$$
\nabla L = 0 = \cases{
\begin{array}{l}
 \lambda  x-\frac 16\frac{1}{n_1^2 n_2 n_3} \\
 \lambda  y-\frac 16 \frac{1}{n_1 n_2^2n_3} \\
 \lambda  z-\frac 16 \frac{1}{n_1 n_2 n_3^2} \\
 \frac{2 \mu  x}{a^2}+\lambda  n_1 \\
 \frac{2 \mu  y}{b^2}+\lambda  n_2\\
 \frac{2 \mu  z}{c^2}+\lambda  n_3 \\
 n_1 x+n_2 y+n_3 z-1 \\
 \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}-1 \\
\end{array}
}
$$

now as $\lambda, \mu$ are generic multipliers, making $\lambda_0 = 6\lambda n_1n_2n_3,\ \ \mu_0 = 6\mu n_1n_2n_3$ we follow with

$$
\nabla L = 0 = \cases{
\begin{array}{l}
 \lambda_0  x-\frac{1}{n_1} \\
 \lambda_0  y-\frac{1}{n_2} \\
 \lambda_0  z-\frac{1}{n_3} \\
 \frac{2 \mu_0  x}{a^2}+\lambda_0  n_1 \\
 \frac{2 \mu_0  y}{b^2}+\lambda_0  n_2\\
 \frac{2 \mu_0  z}{c^2}+\lambda_0  n_3 \\
 n_1 x+n_2 y+n_3 z-1 \\
 \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}-1 \\
\end{array}
}
$$

etc.